# new to ubuntu 14.04.1 lts Can't Connect to network

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers

Hi I am brand new to Ubuntu. I have been able to install and set up a dual boot with Windows 10 and can successfully maneuver between OS's after some struggles. I am not able to access my wireless network via Ubuntu though. From what I have read in other peoples questions it sounds like its a driver issue with my wifi card. After running lspci I see that Ubuntu sees my network card. But I don't know where to go from there. I am too new to know what my next steps should be?
I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. My network card is a Realtek RTL8190.
I was asked to update my post with the out put from lspci -knn | grep Net -A2  so here we are. Hope someone can help :)

```
   desktop:$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
   05:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8190 802.11n PCI Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8190]
           Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8190 802.11n PCI Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8190]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Hey with finals I have been busy. Only just now was able to update my question. Hope this gives enough info.